# BullsEye Code coverage on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Has anyone used BullsEye on visual studio 2005? I am trying it from last few days but no coverage file is created.
If I am running a same project on qt creator via qbs build, then everything works fine, that means there is no issue with the bullseye installation. (We have start development files of visual studio as well qt creator). I am not sure which setting is not done in visual studio!!

1. I installed bullseye and then selected "Enable/Disable BullsEye Coverage Build" from tools menu.
2. Also executed the command cov01 -1 before building, and have tried almost all the options given on "http://www.bullseye.com/help/tool-microsoft.html". Everything looks fine on my visual studio !!

Looks like my visual studio build is not  calling the environment variable of bullseye "COVFILE". Although building via incredibuild a message is received that bullseye will be used but if i give a wrong path in environment variable COVEFILE no error is thrown that means the environment variable is not called at all !!

Please suggest any solution for this problem.

Comment: Sorry, don't know the answer to your question, but are you aware, that VS2015 is free for private use and small teams? Working with a 10 year old compiler and IDE, will lead to all kinds of productivity problems.

Comment: No actually these products are very old, I am just implementing the bullseye on these projects for re-testing work. Although I think you are right let me try it on  vs2010 or 2015. Thanks :)

Comment: Bingoo, worked on VS2010. So now the question is "Is BullsEye "BullseyeCoverage-8.9.55-Windows" is compatible with VS2005? I guess it should be because most of our projects were made in VS2005 and I don't thing the higher management will make such a huge mistake to purchase a code coverage tool that is not compatible with more than 50% projects !!

Answer (score 1):

Edit the PATH variable and put BullsEye bin directory path before visual studio path